# The process cannot access the DTSX file - SSIS installation

Tags: ssis, ssis-2008

I'm trying to deploy SSIS package using "Integration Service Deployment Menufast"

I have around 12 packages. Error is showing for pakage3.
Getting one error:

> The process cannot access the file 'E:\LOC\3Pkg.dtsx' because its being used by another process.

How to resolve this? Is there any service I need to stop before this deployment?

Please note that, I have disable the job before this installation. Also, I just made sure that no one else is using this.

Is there any other ways to check if any applications are using those packages?

Please suggest! Thanks.

Comment: [File in use by another process](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2013/04/file-in-use-by-another-process.html) But if E is a network drive, that's going to be a different matter

Answer (score 0):

Probable it is locked by the DtsDebugHost. 
Open the Task Manager and locate DtsDebugHost.exe under Processes and end that process (could be multiple times, end them all). Now try running the package again.